# Custom tag in AWS Polly speech mark file

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, text-to-speech, amazon-polly

I want to use a custom tag for images in my text thats processed by Polly.

If this is the text sent to Polly to be processed: `This is a {image1} dinosaur`

then I'd like to get a file with these speech mark entries in it:

```
{"time":0,"type":"sentence","start":71,"end":208,"value":"This is a dinosaur."}
{"time":1900,"type":"ssml","start":131,"end":154,"value":"{image1}"}
```

But what I get with my code is this:

```
{"time":0,"type":"sentence","start":71,"end":208,"value":"This is a <\/prosody><mark name='{image1}'\/><prosody rate='110%' volume='x-loud'> dinosaur."}
{"time":1900,"type":"ssml","start":131,"end":154,"value":"{image1}"}
```

This is my code:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;
import com.amazonaws.services.polly.AmazonPolly;
import com.amazonaws.services.polly.AmazonPollyClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.polly.model.OutputFormat;
import com.amazonaws.services.polly.model.SpeechMarkType;
import com.amazonaws.services.polly.model.StartSpeechSynthesisTaskRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.polly.model.StartSpeechSynthesisTaskResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.polly.model.SynthesisTask;
import com.amazonaws.services.polly.model.TextLengthExceededException;
import com.amazonaws.services.polly.model.TextType;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object;
import com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PollyService {
  private AmazonPolly pollyClient;
  private AmazonS3 s3Client;
  private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
  private SsmlTextService ssmlTextService;

  public PollyService() {
    String pollyRegion = System.getenv("ENV_VAR");
    if (pollyRegion == null) {
      pollyRegion = System.getenv("AWS_REGION");
    }
    this.s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();
    this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    pollyClient = AmazonPollyClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(pollyRegion).build();
    ssmlTextService = new SsmlTextService();
  }

  public static String getDocumentId(String mp3File) {
    String documentId = mp3File;

    int pos = mp3File.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (pos > 0) {
      pos = mp3File.lastIndexOf('.', pos - 1);
      if (pos > 0) {
        documentId = mp3File.substring(0, pos);
      }
    }
    return documentId;
  }

  public PollyResult synthesizeLongSpeech(
          String fullText, String outbucket, String documentId, PollyParams params, LambdaLogger logger) {

    //Replace image tags with SSML format
//    String processedText = replaceImageTagsWithSSML(fullText);
    String text = ssmlTextService.getSsmlText(params.getDomain(), fullText, params.getSpeekingRate(), logger);
    StartSpeechSynthesisTaskRequest request = new StartSpeechSynthesisTaskRequest()
        .withOutputS3BucketName(outbucket)
        .withOutputS3KeyPrefix(documentId)
        .withOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Mp3)
//            .withSpeechMarkTypes(SpeechMarkType.Ssml)
//            .withTextType(TextType.Text)
        .withVoiceId(params.getVoiceId())
        .withTextType(TextType.Ssml)
        .withSampleRate(params.getSampleRate())
        .withSnsTopicArn(System.getenv("ENV_VAR"))
        .withEngine(params.getEngine())
        .withLanguageCode(params.getLanguageCode())
        .withText(text);
    try {
      StartSpeechSynthesisTaskResult result = pollyClient.startSpeechSynthesisTask(request);
      SynthesisTask task = result.getSynthesisTask();
      return new PollyResult(true, task.getTaskId(), task.getRequestCharacters());
    } catch (TextLengthExceededException e) {
      logger.log(e.getMessage());
      return new PollyResult(false, null, null);
    }
  }

  public PollyResult synthesizeLongSpeechmarks(
          String fullText, String outbucket, String customerId, String documentId, PollyParams params, LambdaLogger logger) {
    //Replace image tags with SSML format
//    String processedText = replaceImageTagsWithSSML(fullText);
    String text = ssmlTextService.getSsmlText(params.getDomain(), fullText, params.getSpeekingRate(), logger);
    String destinationBucket = outbucket;
    String pollyRegion = System.getenv("ENV_VAR");
    if (!System.getenv("AWS_REGION").equals(pollyRegion)) {
      destinationBucket = destinationBucket + "." + pollyRegion;
    }

    StartSpeechSynthesisTaskRequest request = new StartSpeechSynthesisTaskRequest()
        .withOutputS3BucketName(destinationBucket)
        .withOutputS3KeyPrefix("polly_speechmarks/" + customerId + "." + documentId)
        .withOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Json)
            .withSpeechMarkTypes(SpeechMarkType.Ssml, SpeechMarkType.Sentence)
            .withVoiceId(params.getVoiceId())
        .withTextType(TextType.Ssml)
        .withSampleRate(params.getSampleRate())
        .withSnsTopicArn(System.getenv("ENV_VAR"))
        .withEngine(params.getEngine())
        .withLanguageCode(params.getLanguageCode())
        .withText(text);
    try {
      StartSpeechSynthesisTaskResult result = pollyClient.startSpeechSynthesisTask(request);
      SynthesisTask task = result.getSynthesisTask();
      return new PollyResult(true, task.getTaskId(), task.getRequestCharacters());
    } catch (TextLengthExceededException e) {
      return new PollyResult(false, null, null);
    }
  }

}
```

and also

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;
import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SsmlTextService {
  public String getSsmlText(String domain, String text, int speakingRate, LambdaLogger logger) {
    if (speakingRate < 20 || speakingRate > 200) {
      speakingRate = 100;
    }

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("<speak>");
    if (domain != null && domain.length() > 0) {
      builder.append("<amazon:domain name='").append(domain).append("'>");
    }

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{image\\d+\\}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    int lastMatchEnd = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
      // Open prosody tag
      builder.append("<prosody rate='").append(speakingRate).append("%' volume='x-loud'>");
      // Append text before the {imageN} placeholder
      builder.append(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(text.substring(lastMatchEnd, matcher.start())));
      // Close prosody tag
      builder.append("</prosody>");

      // Append the <mark> tag for {imageN}
      builder.append("<mark name='").append(matcher.group()).append("'/>");

      lastMatchEnd = matcher.end();
    }

    // Append any remaining text after the last {imageN} placeholder
    // Open prosody tag
    builder.append("<prosody rate='").append(speakingRate).append("%' volume='x-loud'>");
    builder.append(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(text.substring(lastMatchEnd)));
    // Close prosody tag
    builder.append("</prosody>");

    if (domain != null && domain.length() > 0) {
      builder.append("</amazon:domain>");
    }
    builder.append("</speak>");

    return builder.toString();
  }


  private String processTextForSsml(String text) {
    StringBuffer processedText = new StringBuffer();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{image\\d+\\}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    int lastEnd = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
      // Append text part
      processedText.append(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(text.substring(lastEnd, matcher.start())));

      // Append mark tag outside prosody
      processedText.append("</prosody>")
              .append("<mark name='")
              .append(matcher.group())
              .append("'/>")
              .append("<prosody rate='100%' volume='x-loud'>");

      lastEnd = matcher.end();
    }

    // Append the remaining part of the text
    processedText.append(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(text.substring(lastEnd)));

    return processedText.toString();
  }
}
```

Any advice or recommendation, much appreciated. Thank you

Edit::
Something else might worth bringing up is that initially I had difficulty getting the type ssml speechmark entry to generate so I couldnt get:
'''
{"time":1900,"type":"ssml","start":131,"end":154,"value":"{image1}"}

```
but I managed to get that by adding 
'''
            .withSpeechMarkTypes(SpeechMarkType.Ssml, SpeechMarkType.Sentence)
'''

Before I had just
'''
            .withSpeechMarkType(SpeechMarkType.Sentence)
```

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want the output to be `This is a dinosaur.` or do you want it to be `This is a <\/prosody><mark name='{image1}'\/><prosody rate='110%' volume='x-loud'> dinosaur.`? Because your code is certainly replacing `{image}` with all the `prosody` stuff. Can you please clarify what is wrong / what you want to happen?

Comment: I want my output to be 
'''This is a dinosaur'''.

Comment: But what I get is:


{"time":0,"type":"sentence","start":71,"end":208,"value":"This is a dinosaur."}
{"time":1900,"type":"ssml","start":131,"end":154,"value":"{image1}"}

Comment: In your question you say "I'd like to get a file with these speech mark entries in it", but in your comment you say that you just want "This is a dinosaur". There seems to be a mismatch between your statements.

Comment: Apologies. In my comment response I was referring solely to the type=sentence speechmark metadata entry. The output in its entirety, should be:  {"time":0,"type":"sentence","start":71,"end":208,"value":"This is a dinosaur."} {"time":1900,"type":"ssml","start":131,"end":154,"value":"{image1}"}

Comment: Then why have you written code that says things like `builder.append("<prosody rate='").append(speakingRate).append("%' volume='x-loud'>");
      // Append text before the {imageN} placeholder`?

Comment: So the reason is the synthesizeLongSpeechmarks() function. We pass the text and for the speechmarks to be generated. Polly recognizes the {imageN} as ssml and creates the relevant entry in the generated metadata, but it doesn't remove the custom tag automatically from the string content of the value property of the entry with type=sentence. I did not find much in terms of theory so I started trying to embed the part I want removed and only referenced in a separate speechmark entry of type ssml with various tags hoping that one of them would work